# How can i change the Gradle default lib path?

Tags: maven, build, gradle, project

In maven,we can change the dependency path like this:

```
<localRepository>/lib/maven.repository</localRepository>
```

but how can i change the default Gradle lib path?

Comment: Which location you mean? This where dependencies are downloaded or the one where artifacts are installed?

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to do so:

- Set the GRADLE_USER_HOME environment variable
- Set gradle.user.home system property
- Use command line parameter --gradle-user-home

Answer (score 0):

If you configure you maven local path in `~/.m2/settings.xml` like you described (`<localRepository>/path/to/files</localRepository>`) Gradle should handle that.

If it doesn't for any reason, you can use custom maven repository like:

```
repositories {
    mavenRepo urls: ['file:///path/to/files']
}
```